# Create Node tree with nest. (Using swift-parsing)

Tags: swift

I want to identify the text between the Tags.
For that I am trying to generate a NodeTree.

I have text like this

`"aaa<small>bbb</small>ccc*ddddd*"`

The definition of Node is as this.
Node Tree is represented by an array of Node.

```swift
enum Node: Equatable {
    case text(_ text: String)
    case bold(children: [Self]) // between **
    case small(children: [Self]) // between <small></small>
    case italic(children: [Self]) // between <i></i>
}
```

I defined a Parser like this.

This discussion was used as a reference for how to make it:
[Parse string with HTML tag and transform to Text](https://github.com/pointfreeco/swift-parsing/discussions/30)

```
class MyParcer {
    lazy var body =  Many {
        smallTag
        italicTag
        boldAsta
        textNormal
        Rest().compactMap {
                $0.isEmpty
                ? nil
                : Node.text(String($0))
            }
    }

    private lazy var smallTag = Parse {
        "<small>"
        PrefixUpTo("</small>")
            .compactMap { [weak self] in
                return $0.isEmpty
                ? nil
                : Node.small(
                    children: self?.parseChildren(String($0)) ?? [.text(String($0))]
                )
            }
        "</small>"
    }

    private lazy var boldAsta = Parse {
        "*"
        PrefixUpTo("*")
        "*"
    }.compactMap { [weak self] content in
        return content.isEmpty
        ? nil
        : Node.bold(
            children: self?.parseChildren(String(content)) ?? [.text(String(content))]
        )
    }

    private lazy var italicTag = Parse {
        "<i>"
        PrefixUpTo("</i>")
            .compactMap { [weak self] in
                return $0.isEmpty
                ? nil
                : Node.italic(
                    children: self?.parseChildren(String($0)) ?? [.text(String($0))]
                )
            }
        "</i>"
    }

    private func parseChildren(_ content: String) -> [Node] {
        do {
            return try body.parse(content)
        } catch {
            return [.text(content)]
        }
    }

     private lazy var textNormal = OneOf {
        PrefixUpTo("*")
            .compactMap {
              $0.isEmpty
              ? nil
                : Node.text(String($0))
            } 

       PrefixUpTo("<i>")
            .compactMap {
              $0.isEmpty
              ? nil
                : Node.text(String($0))
            }

        PrefixUpTo("<small>")
            .compactMap {
              $0.isEmpty
              ? nil
                : Node.text(String($0))
            }
    }
}
```

This parser cannot correctly parse text with some nesting

This Parser can nest text with different attributes

```
// This test is success
func testNest1() throws {
        let p = p.body
        let input = "<small>abc*123*abc</small>"
        let output = [
            Node.small(
                children: [
                    .text("abc"),
                    .italic(children: [.text("123")]),
                    .text("abc")
                ]
            )
        ]

        XCTAssertEqual(
            try p.parse(input),
            output
        )
    }
```

However, nesting text with the same attributes will not parse correctly

```
// This test is failure
func testNest2() throws {
        let p = p.body
        let input = "<small>abc<small>123</small>abc</small>" // using same attributes
        let output = [
            MfmNode.small(
                children: [
                    .text("abc"),
                    .small(children: [.text("123")]),
                    .text("abc")
                ]
            )
        ]

        XCTAssertEqual(
            try p.parse(input), // [.small(children: [.text("abc<small>123"), ]), .text("abc</small>")]
            output
        )
    }
```

The problem is that </small> , which should be a child element, is used as the parent's closeTag

Others such as these are not parsed correctly
<small>abc<small>def</small>ghi<small>jkl</small>mno</small>

Is there anyone who can give me any advice?

The same information was written in the discussion in the repository:
https://github.com/pointfreeco/swift-parsing/discussions/339